# How do I call class methods with Bukkit API?

Tags: java, api, methods, load, bukkit

I'm trying to get into bukkit plugin development but I am stuck. I am currently learning java and I feel like I have enough knowledge to make a plugin- except I'm missing the most important thing. I'm trying to use the loadChunk() method or the load() method to load a game chunk. I thought what I would do is something like `Chunk chunk = new chunk();` but that spits out the `chunk cannot be resolved to a type` error message. If I try `Chunk()` with a capital then I get this error: `Cannot instantiate the type Chunk`. I also know if the Chunk/World method were static then I would just have to do `Chunk.load()` or `World.loadChunk()` to load the chunk. Is it better to use the chunk's load method or the world's loadChunk method for loading specific chunks? I understand that this is a beginner question, so if you can describe how you know what to do so that in the future I can figure out what I'm supposed to do.

UPDATE:
Thanks for the help. This is what I used in case anyone views this looking for an answer

```
World world = Bukkit.getWorld(worldName);
Chunk chunk = world.getChunkAt(x,y);
```

`worldName` is whatever is the name of the world and `x,y` are the x and y coordinates of the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Chunk chunk = new chunk();
```

> chunk cannot be resolved to a type

It is `Chunk`, not `chunk`.

---

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk();
```

> Cannot instantiate the type Chunk

You must use [`World.getChunkAt(...)`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/World.html#getChunkAt(int,%20int)) to build a `Chunk` object.

---

> Is it better to use the chunk's load method or the world's loadChunk method for loading specific chunks?

No one is deprecated. It depends on you.

Comment: Where were you able to find out that to construct a chunk object you had to put a World.getChunkAt()? Also knowing that you don't have to make a world variable, how were you able to tell that it was static? I'm looking at the JavaDocs and it doesn't tell me all of this information. Is it just trial and error and assumption?

Comment: @JacksonML I guess it's experience. I also work with Bukkit and never even thought of using the ```Chunk()``` constructor.